# AWS ScheduleExpression trigger Lambda once with some delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to invoke a lambda function in AWS once it has been deployed to the stack. I am using `ScheduleExpression` for this with a cron expression `cron(*/5 * ? * * *)` which will run every 5 minutes.
Is it possible to use `at` in place of `cron` something like this `at now + 5 minutes`.

Or is there a better way to invoke lambda after is has been deployed to the stack?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use `at`.

AWS Lambda supports standard `rate` and `cron` expressions for frequencies of up to once per minute.

Also note that all scheduled events use UTC+0 time zone, and the minimum precision for a schedule is one minute. Your scheduled rule runs within that minute, but not on the precise 0th second.

[More on rate & cron with AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html).